# What is making this sound?

Tags: macos

I have an M1 Macbook Pro running Ventura.  For months now it has been making this sound

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-2xqZSxqvyVx6Skzd4rZu-iIgFF5aMFs/view?usp=sharing

something like 3 or 4 times an hour, at seemingly random times.  There is never any accompanying notification.  I have played every audio file on the system I could find with locate and grep, and it doesn't match any of them.  I'm hoping somebody recognizes it so I can eliminate it.

Comment: The downloaded file of the sound plays a "whoop" noise, followed by a song from Girlyman, a musical group. Do you hear the "whoop" or the song or both?

Comment: @DavidRecallsMonica - I checked this on two different devices, it's only a 1 second "whoop" wound with no song afterward.  Maybe you have something queued up your music player?

Comment: It sounds like a notification for a chat program.  What apps do you have running?

Comment: @Allan Thanks, I'm sure that's it...Girlyman is music that I sometimes listen to.

Comment: Unless you get lucky and someone recognizes the sound, you’ll have to go through the list of apps that play sounds in the Notifications settings panel.

Comment: @LincD. that would be an excellent answer to explain how to perform that search on macOS. Ideally with one screen shot or so…